# Show the autocomplete match as preview text in vim

Tags: vim, autocomplete

Is it possible with Vim itself or a plugin to display the autocomplete option inline?[image: example]

If not is there a way to display text in vim without inserting it into the buffer?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the popup menu ([`:help popupmenu-completion`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#popupmenu-completion); it usually displays [a subset of] the available choices) by removing `menu[one]` from the [`'completeopt'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27completeopt%27) option. Then, the first candidate (or `longest` common part) is directly inserted into the buffer, and `<C-n>` cycles through candidates at that location. To remove the current suggested completion and return to the original state before the completion, press `<C-e>`.

That technically still (if only temporarily) inserts the candidate into the buffer, but I think it closely fits what you're asking for, and is built-in. To display text without inserting, there's currently only a (rather crude) workaround of using the [`:help conceal`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#conceal) feature to change the appearance of individual characters (for a static text, matching the exact location in the buffer via `\%l` and `\%c`) into something else via `matchadd()`. However, this only works if there's existing text; it wouldn't work at the end of a line. Currently, a *generic overlay feature* is being discussed on the the [vim_dev mailing list](https://www.vim.org/community.php), but it is in very early stages.

Comment: thanks for your answer, and specifically for pointing me towards the dev mailing list. i subscribed to it and i am looking forward for the overlay feature to mature.

Comment: It's not yet clear whether someone will pick up that feature, but there was quite some interest for such functionality. Let's hope for the best, and feel free to actively contribute your feedback on vim_dev as well!